# Does Toriyama keep increasing Beerus’ power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball

In BoG it was stated that Beerus was using 70% of his power against the Super Saiyan God.

Then we saw Super Saipan Blue being weaker than Beerus (while technically, regardless if it is a 50x multiplier or not, it should have overpowered the GoD).

After many arcs, when Goku And Vegeta had grown hugely more powerful than before, we see perfected SSJB Vegeta losing to Beerus (manga only).

Recently, we also got to see SSBE Vegeta (post Yardratian training) losing to a weak Hakai from the God of Destruction.

I mean, isn’t Toriyama just increasing Beerus’ power every arc? We have been told that he used 70% of his power against SSG, but now he can even defeat an enraged, super-trained SSBE while playing around!

What could be the possible in-story reason for this (except for making the story more interesting, of course!)?

Comment: I can't post an answer to this because I dont have references to post, but if you follow Dragon Ball closely you clearly see. 1- There is no in story explanation 2- They no longer follow that idea that Beerus has 70% of SGD power 3- Dragon Ball does this a lot,  it throws a lot of ideas and it doesnt care too much if they contradict each other 4- Many fans pretend there is an in story explanation but they are explanations created by them to keep the story consistent.

Comment: @Pablo , I understand what you’re saying, DB has some major issues, especially in Super, but they do need an explanation... Toriyama can’t always go around saying, “Oh! I forgot ‘bout that!”..

Comment: @SK-the-Learner Beerus' power comes from his status paired with this innate power and training, which I guess stands for the strength of his willpower. He is more powerful because he has a stronger will. You'll notice that most side characters (cough cough, Krillin) are weaker because they aren't as tenacious and singleminded as the likes of Goku or Vegeta.

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR willpower can be a source of power, but it can not provide several fold multiplication of power without proper training in years (Beerus has not been shown to do any training since those 39 years of sleep). Other character (like Goku and Vegeta) not only had a strong will, but they also implemented it in the form of intense training, while Krillin did not cope up with higher tiers of training’s that the Saiyans did.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, he only said he used 70% in the movie, which isn’t canon to the show or manga. In the show/manga (always go by the manga though, because the show isn’t canon to the manga, which is the original source), he never said how much power he was using. Basically, you should forget about trying to scale Beerus’ power.